# This badge is awarded once per review type - meaning

Tags: support, badges

I recently got a Custodian badge and the tooltip on it says "This badge is awarded once per review type"

What does this mean? What are the review types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/

Comment: why  the downvote? the link posted doesn't make any difference. I have checked that twice now???

Comment: Ok I got you. I see there are sections in that page but why the downvote?

Comment: 1) don't assume I downvoted just because I commented, crap like that is what makes me _not_ want to comment when I actually downvote. 2) review tasks are tasks in `/review`.

Comment: @tunmisefasipe the link is relevant because the badge is given each time you perform a review of a different review type (review types are listed at `/review`)

Comment: this was my first time and it just appeared. I didn't know what I did to get until I click on the badge - I have done reviews in the past and I don't know why the last one I did was so important that I got the badge. @Yannis Rizos I actually assumed that. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos I never knew that page exist. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/review/, it appears there are five review types:

1. First Posts
2. Late Answers
3. Low Quality Posts
4. Suggested Edits
5. Close Votes

Comment: It's 5 no longer. )